# calling object from class in java

Tags: java

guys i9 know it is dummy qustion but i am beginner .. i have this class

```
public class threadLocal {
private static ThreadLocal<String> myThreadLocal;

public threadLocal(){
    myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}

public static ThreadLocal<String> getMyThreadLocal() {
    return myThreadLocal;
}

public static void setMyThreadLocal(ThreadLocal<String> myThreadLocal) {
    threadLocal.myThreadLocal = myThreadLocal;
}
}
```

and i want to call it like this in another class

```
myThreadLocal.setMyThreadLocal("patrick");
```

so what changes should i do in threadLocal class ??

Comment: yesss it is ... ithreadLlocal contatins object from ThreadLocal

Comment: If _myThreadLocal_ is of type _threadLocal_ you can't call _setMyThreadLocal_ with the argument "patrick", because it expects an object of type _ThreadLocal<String>_, not an object of type _String_.

Comment: @ModusTollens so waht should changes i do to call it with argument patrick  ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can change the method argument to receive a _String_ and construct a _ThreadLocal<String>_ object from that, or you keep the argument as type _ThreadLocal<String>_ and call the method with an object of type _ThreadLocal<String>_.

Comment: Does the ThreadLocal class have a constructor that uses a String as arument?

Comment: I think it is too unclear what you are trying to achieve to give a good answer to this question. What is this code for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should rewrite your class this way.

```
public class threadLocal {
 private static ThreadLocal<String> myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();

 public static String getMyThreadLocal() {
    return myThreadLocal.get();
  }

 public static void setMyThreadLocal(String str) {
    myThreadLocal.set(str);
  }
}
```

While calling, you may just call

```
threadLocal.getMyThreadLocal()
```

Comment: and how call it in main class ??

Comment: threadLocal local = new threadLocal();
 local.setMyThreadLocal("dsfd");

Comment: `setMyThreadLocal` is static, so you need to call the method on the class. So: `threadLocal.setMyThreadLocal("patrick");`

Comment: BTW the classnames in java usually start with Capital letter.